# AWS lambda typescript handler schema validation

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm fairly new to Typescript and I'm looking for advice on how to access the event.body type from the handler function rather than defining an interface. I'm using the serverless aws-nodejs-typescript template.

The request schema:

[image]

handler function:

[image]

As you can see the createBeneficiary function accepts any type, now I would prefer for it to be strongly typed, I can create and interface but I wondered if there was a better way since it's already defined in the request schema. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do the following:

```js
import type { FromSchema } from 'json-schema-to-ts';

function createBeneficiary(request: FromSchema<typeof schema>) {
  // request.domesticAccountId should be a string
}
```